# Excel conditionnal formating using a format reference table

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

I have a table with values:

[image]

, and a second table with reference values and the companion format:

[image]

The target result is:

[image]

Is it possible to do it without VBA?

The only solution I have found is: 1) filter each reference value at a time, 2) copy/past the value from the reference table to the first cell, 3) propagate the value with its format with the mouse, 4) loop to (1). Not very efficient !

Comment: This can be done with conditional formatting

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad How? I think the idea here is that if the format is changed in the reference table, that format should now apply to the CF formatted cells. I don't see that working without VBA.

Comment: Agreed. You can't set a format of a cell using a reference format. Though I wish we could. 

Shameless plug for feedback request to allow formatting via function calls: https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/idea/145b0e36-96f1-ec11-a81b-000d3a03dba2

Comment: I believe what you are trying to do is avoid the rule-making process in the conditional formatting dialogs and just provide “example” formats in a table that are then applied to cells by formula logic.  I agree with teylyn, that would not be a use case for conditional formatting, and relegates you to scripting in VBA.

Comment: If you want to get the cell format with Conditional Formatting, you can only use the VBA. The build in feature cannot get and save the cell formats in the conditional formatting rules.